# how to derive the stochastic differential equation of this process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals

How can I derive the SDE for the vasicek model :

$$r_t = 0.1  + 0.1 e^{-t} + e^{-t}\int_0 ^t e^s dB_s$$

From observation, the SDE vasicek's model is such that:

$$dr_t = b(a-r_t)dt + \sigma dB_t$$

but I do not know how to link the two.
The answer is

$$dr_t = (0.1 - r_t)dt + dB_t$$

Comment: Can you differentiate the identity $$e^tr_t=.1e^t+.1+\int_0^te^sdB_s\ ?$$

Comment: Would I need to apply one of ito's formula? I am not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_t = \int_0^t e^s dB_s$.  Then 
    $$r_t = f(t, X_t) = .1 + .1e^{-t} + e^{-t}X_t$$
By Ito's Lemma:
$$dr_t = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dX_t + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{dx^2}Var(X_t))dt$$

So:
\begin{eqnarray*}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dX_t + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2f}{dx^2}Var(X_t))dt &=& e^{-t}dX_t + (-.1e^{-t} + e^{-t}X_t)dt \\
&=& e^{-t}e^tdB_t + (-.1e^{-t} - e^{-t}X_t)dt \\
&=& dB_t + (-.1e^{-t} - e^{-t}e^t(r_t - .1 - .1 e^{-t})dt \\
&=& dB_t + (.1 - r_t)dt \\
\end{eqnarray*}